# why async in node.js in loop giving error

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, node.js, redis

I have this part of code in  my application.

```
 card.getcard(command, function(toproceed,resultscard) {
    console.log('entry other cards api result'+sys.inspect(resultscard));
    if (resultscard.length==0) {
      return proceed(false,{errno:'011','queueno' : request.queueno, message:'there is no access card for particular gib'});
    }

    for (var i=0; i<resultscard.length;i++) {
      console.log('card owner'+resultscard[i].owner);

      //checking that any users is in inside of gib
      server.wrap(function(){
        server.getchannel("channels."+request.gibid+'-I', function(err, channel) {
          if (channel.users) {
            var arr=channel.users.split(',');
            if (functions.in_array(resultscard[i].owner, arr)) {
              response.users.push(resultscard[i].owner);
            }
          }
        });
        if(i==resultscard.length-1) {
          if (response.users.length<=0) {
            //here need to send sorry event that no owner is online
            request._command='sorry';
          } else {
            request._command='knock';
          } 
          return proceed(true,response);
        }
      });

    }
  });
```

while executing this giving me error .

```
entry other cards api result[ { cardid: 16,
    cardtype: 'A',
    status: 'A',
    refername: 'rahulgib',
    refertype: 'G',
    owner: 'rahul' },
  { cardid: 27,
    cardtype: 'A',
    status: 'A',
    refername: 'rahulgib',
    refertype: 'G',
    owner: 'namita' } ]
card ownerrahul
card ownernamita

node.js:178
        throw e; // process.nextTick error, or 'error' event on first tick
        ^
TypeError: Cannot read property 'owner' of undefined
    at Object.callback (/home/myhome directory /redisyoungib/lib/yapi.js:271:50)
    at RedisClient.return_reply (/usr/local/lib/node/.npm/redis/0.6.0/package/index.js:384:29)
    at HiredisReplyParser.<anonymous> (/usr/local/lib/node/.npm/redis/0.6.0/package/index.js:78:14)
    at HiredisReplyParser.emit (events.js:64:17)
    at HiredisReplyParser.execute (/usr/local/lib/node/.npm/redis/0.6.0/package/lib/parser/hiredis.js:35:22)
    at RedisClient.on_data (/usr/local/lib/node/.npm/redis/0.6.0/package/index.js:325:27)
    at Socket.<anonymous> (/usr/local/lib/node/.npm/redis/0.6.0/package/index.js:90:14)
    at Socket.emit (events.js:64:17)
    at Socket._onReadable (net.js:673:14)
    at IOWatcher.onReadable [as callback] (net.js:177:10)
```

I am not getting why it is giving this error ?

get card gives the result from mysql of card

wrap function executed the callback  function .

getchannel return the data from redis .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The functions you're creating and passing into `server.getchannel` are closures over the `i` variable (well, over everything in scope, but it's `i` we're concerned with). They get an *enduring reference* to `i`, not a *copy* of its value as of when the function was created. That means when the function runs, it uses the *current* value of `i`, not the value as it was when the function was created. The upshot is that *all* of those functions will use the same value of `i`, which is the value as of the end of the loop. Since that's beyond the end of the array, `resultscard[i]` is `undefined` and so trying to read an `owner` property from it fails. (More about closures: [*Closures are not complicated*](http://blog.niftysnippets.org/2008/02/closures-are-not-complicated.html))

So what you want to do is get those functions to close over something that's a *copy* of the value of `i`. The usual way to do that is to have a factory function that creates them and that accepts the value to use as an argument. The factory function creates the callback function, which closes over the argument, whose value doesn't change.

Without reading through it too carefully, applying that to your code probably looks *something* like this:

```
card.getcard(command, function(toproceed,resultscard) {
    console.log('entry other cards api result'+sys.inspect(resultscard));
    if (resultscard.length==0) {
      return proceed(false,{errno:'011','queueno' : request.queueno, message:'there is no access card for particular gib'});
    }

    for (var i=0; i<resultscard.length;i++) {
      console.log('card owner'+resultscard[i].owner);

      //checking that any users is in inside of gib
      server.wrap(function(){
        server.getchannel("channels."+request.gibid+'-I', makeCallback(i));
        // Call the factory function, passing in `i` -----^
        if(i==resultscard.length-1) {
          if (response.users.length<=0) {
            //here need to send sorry event that no owner is online
            request._command='sorry';
          } else {
            request._command='knock';
          } 
          return proceed(true,response);
        }
      });

    }

    // The factory function    
    function makeCallback(index) {
      return function(err, channel) {
        if (channel.users) {
          var arr=channel.users.split(',');
          // Note we use `index` -- our argument -- not `i` below
          if (functions.in_array(resultscard[index].owner, arr)) {
            response.users.push(resultscard[index].owner);
          }
        }
      };
    }
  });
```

Now the callback we create in `makeCallback` closes over the `index` argument for the call that created it, which nothing other changes. We pass `i` in, and there we are. It's still a closure over the other things (because of where `makeCallback` is defined), but it uses `index` with them so it handles the right entry.

Comment: @TJ what should i do to remove the error ? and execute my program properly

Comment: @Rahul: I've added some notes and code illustrating the usual approach.

Comment: @TJ i have update my code acc. to answer , and test it it , gives me error that `resultscard is not defined ` , what should i do for this

Comment: @Rahul: It sounds like you've put the `makeCallback` function in the wrong place. Note how in the above, it's *inside* the anonymous function you're passing into `getcard`, so that it (and therefore the functions it creates) closes over `resultscard` and such.

Comment: @TJ i have tried with putting makeCallBack function in the getcard , but still error of resultscard not defined is coming

Comment: @Rahul: Unless `resultscard` is being passed in undefined, it *can't* be undefined in the functions created by `makeCallback`. Are you sure it's `resultscard` and not `resultscard[index]` that's undefined? The latter is possible, if whatever is giving you the array has manipulated it between when you scheduled the callback and when the callback occurred.

Comment: ReferenceError: resultscard is not defined
    at Object.callback (/home/myhome/redisyoungib/lib/yapi.js:288:9) this is the error coming

Comment: @Rahul: I don't know what else to tell you. With the function placed as it is above, provided `resultscard` is defined on the second line (`console.log('entry other cards api result'+sys.inspect(resultscard));`), it **will** be defined within the callbacks. There is nothing *in the code above* that's assigning to `resultscard`, and it's in-scope for the `makeCallback` function provided it's where it is above, within the anonymous function you're passing into `getcards`. That error means `makeCallback` is in the wrong place, or you have code assigning to `resultscard` that you haven't quoted.

Comment: @TJ m sorry , i was checking in the wrong directory , now i check in right directory it is working , thanks

Comment: Insteading making seperate function we can do it by making self executing function like this :`(function(i){
      set.push(function(){
         console.log(i);
      });
   })(i);`

Comment: @Rahul: That's still a separate function, it's just an anonymous one. Or more accurately, a bunch of anonymous ones, because the function will be *REcreated* on every loop, which is unnecessarily inefficient. It's also less clear what's going on. The joy of using a nice, clear, named function is that it's more efficient than re-creating functions and makes it clearer what's being done.

Answer (score 1):

This is one of the trickiest parts of javascript scope imo.

When you're inside a loop and you're creating anonymous functions based on the index from a loop, you need to do something like **bind**, **currying**, or **anonymous self executing functions** to make sure you are capturing the right value.

The concept is illustrated by this example:

```
var set = [];

// Store a list of functions in an array
for (var i = 0; i<5; i++) {
   set.push(function(){
      console.log(i);
   });
}

// Pull the functions back out and execute them
for (var x = 0; x<5; x++) {
   set[x]();
}
```

The output of this is:

```
5
5
5
5
5
```

Expected? No. You'd expect 0, 1, 2, 3, 4

This is because the variables based on the index for the outer scope (outside the function you've created) is not copied, its evaluated when the function is executed (some time later, after the loop is already through).

To get the desired affect, you can do any of the things I mentioned above. This (which is arguably the simplest) is a **self executing anonymous function**:

```
var set = [];

// Store a list of functions in an array
for (var i = 0; i<5; i++) {
   (function(i){
      set.push(function(){
         console.log(i);
      });
   })(i);
}

// Pull the functions back out and execute them
for (var x = 0; x<5; x++) {
   set[x]();
}
```

This gives you the desired output of 0, 1, 2, 3, 4 because we've established a new scope by creating a new function, passed in the variable we're interested in (i), and executed the function immediately with the desired parameters. It takes the basic form of (function(a){})(a).

Without knowing the details of your code beyond this block, you might do something like this:

```
card.getcard(command, function(toproceed,resultscard) {
    console.log('entry other cards api result'+sys.inspect(resultscard));
    if (resultscard.length==0) {
      return proceed(false,{errno:'011','queueno' : request.queueno, message:'there is no access card for particular gib'});
    }

    for (var i=0; i<resultscard.length;i++) {
      (function(resultscard, i){
          console.log('card owner'+resultscard[i].owner);

          //checking that any users is in inside of gib
          server.wrap(function(){
            server.getchannel("channels."+request.gibid+'-I', function(err, channel) {
              if (channel.users) {
                var arr=channel.users.split(',');
                if (functions.in_array(resultscard[i].owner, arr)) {
                  response.users.push(resultscard[i].owner);
                }
              }
            });
            if(i==resultscard.length-1) {
              if (response.users.length<=0) {
                //here need to send sorry event that no owner is online
                request._command='sorry';
              } else {
                request._command='knock';
              } 
              return proceed(true,response);
            }
          });
      })(resultscard, i);
    }
});
```